# dedicated template for a Drupal module

Tags: drupal, templates, overriding

I have a Drupal module, that I want to present in a clean page - with no headers, menus, footer ect.  I think all I need is a version of page.tpl.php that contains HTML page headers and  `<?php print $content ?>`  How can I point my module to such a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with [template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/223440).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with Front Page module

[Front Page Module](http://drupal.org/project/front)

Answer (score 0):

the template suggestion technique worked for me!

```
function phptemplate_preprocess(&$variables) {
    global $user;

    $myURL = (basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    if($myURL == 'my_module_name')
    {
        $variables['template_file'] = 'page_my_module'; 
  }
}
```